# Generate explicit maven pom

Tags: maven

I feel like I'm asking for something that someone out there must have already solved, but I've failed to find it yet myself. Where I work, we have loose specifications in our pom files regarding component ranges. We build a lot of small component libraries and pull them together in our apps. This enables us to pick up changes sooner rather than later. However, when approaching a release, we want to slow down the intake on those changes. We often branch some components, but what I/we would really like to do is lock down our pom ranges. The maven version plugin support **versions:resolve-ranges**, but this only locks in our explicit dependencies and not any transitive ones. Ideally, I think I need/want the ability to generate an explicit pom with ALL dependencies specified and locked down. This would allow me to branch my top level component (my application code) and lock in everything else. How does this not exist? I'm missing something, right?

Comment: Doesn't locking in your explicit dependencies take care of your transitive ones as well?

Comment: @VaibhavSagar not if the dependencies of my dependencies aren't locked in themselves... unless I'm confused.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.